# How do I debug "500 Internal Server Error" with Azure Mobile Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I am deploying Azure Mobile Apps to a deployment slot, and am getting the error below within Xamarin iOS.

> 500 The request could not be completed (Internal Server Error)

I have done the following:

- Set `<customErrors mode="Off" ></customErrors>`
- Inspect Application Insights Live Metrics Screen
- Enabled failed request tracing
- Inspect the event logs (2147024891 azure runtime failed to initialize)
- Search for "web service" based DLLs and references in my "web app".  I found some suspicious ones in Application Insights that contain the word "ROLE"

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureWebAppRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
```

View the full [list of references here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn9VA.png)

**Future testing and debugging**

The Azure help page didn't seem to tell me how to enable remote debugging, which is the next thing I'm googling.

(image of the help page that could be more helpful in this regard ;)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing a chapter on this in the ZUMO book: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter8/developing/

Comment: I'm going to read that entire thing, then figure out some way to diff the stuff I read with the inevitable ongoing updates. ALSO, found my exception, though I need to figure out where the error "went" in my app... It went here: ApplicationInsights.CreateTelemetryClient().TrackRestAPIException(correlationId, exception);

Comment: Instead of a link, please post the relevant section. If the link goes down, your answer becomes useless